# I used led calculator and it gave me a different solutions, in one of the solutions says " the array draws current of 100 mA from the source"

Tags: resistors

With another solutions mA just goes up, 125 mA, then 175 mA, 250 mA,I want to know which solution is best,the one that draws less mA will be best?

Comment: Please add details of the LED array you are using. A schematic of your setup also.

Answer (score 1):

LED calculators are only as good as the information entered into them. I'd ditch the calculator idea and think about the problem from the ground up. Consider how the current increases on a LED when the voltage across it is increased. The graph below shows various coloured LEDs and typical voltages and currents per LED: -

[image]

Concentrate on the red LED and imagine you had it connected across a bench power supply and you carefully increased the voltage across the LED from 0V upwards to (say) 3 volts. At zero volts there will be no current flow and this is largely the same all the way up to about 1.5 volts.

No current flow means no light output. Here's a better view of what is happening on the graph with low voltages applied to the LED: -

[image]

Maybe at about 1.6 volts the red LED is starting to show signs of taking a small amount of current. This is kind of a threshold and slightly increasing the voltage a little bit will result in a sudden increase in current and the LED is illuminating nicely. At 2 volts, the red LED is taking 25 mA and this might be all the manufacturer recommends - stop at this point or you might damage the LED!

Now usually, the manufacturer of the LED specifies two things: -

- Typical (or maybe maximum) forward current rating
- Typical forward voltage (at the forward current rating)

These two points are on the graph (even if the manufacturer doesn't supply a graph). So, for the red LED, the typical forward current might be 25mA at a voltage of 2V.

So say you have a 9 volt supply and you want to power the LED at 25mA, you can virtually ignore the first 2 volts of the 9V and concentrate on finding a resistor that drops 7 volts when 25mA is flowing. That's easy - it's ohms law - R = V/I = \$\frac{7V}{0.025A}\$ = 280 ohms.

If the battery rises to 10V from 9V the current rises to \$\frac{8V}{280\Omega}\$ = 28.6mA from 25mA. That maybe a little high for the particular LED you have chosen so increase the resistance a bit so that if your 9V supply could increase to 10V then you have the maximum limits covered - probably about 300 ohms would work for this off-the-cuff theoretical example.

All LEDs are different - read the data sheet and understand the maximum current that the device can safely operate at - take ambient temperatures into account on higher powered LEDs too because the LED will reduce the volt drop as temperature rises and this could be the difference between a great LED display and smoke!

LEDs are usually wired in series so, if you have ten red LEDs like the ones above, you need to account for 20 volts of forward volt drop to obtain the current of 25mA and of course you still need to have a current limiting resistor so if the maximum voltage on your power supply is 25 volts then the resistor value is \$\frac{25-20}{0.025}\$ = 200 ohms.

Hope this helps.